# Найти начальное и конечное числа

Tags: c++

Помогите пожалуйста с этим заданием ! Нет идей как можно решить .

Петя и Вася готовились к аттестации по теме "Умножение". Петя задумывал произведение всех натуральных чисел от A до B, а Вася старался угадать начальное и конечное числа. Помогите Васе найти значения A и B. Если решений несколько, выведите то, у которого A наименьшее.

Входные данные

Одно число – произведение чисел. 1 < A ≤ B ≤ 10000.
Выходные данные

В одной строке через пробел два числа: A и B.

Входные данные #1

60

Выходные данные #1

3 5

Comment: так это же разложение на множители :)

Comment: Вообще-то на входе может оказаться 35660-значное число... Получается, нужна реализация длинной арифметики?.. что-то для задачи, даже олимпиадной, сложновато, нет?

Comment: и как это решить ? длинной арифметикой

Comment: @Harry тут много есть вариантов решения. Я бы предложил перебрать A и B. и делать вычисления по 2-3 модулям, дальше из китайской теоремы об остатках получается всё очень даже хорошо. А вычислить остаток исходного числа от деления - хоть "в столбик". я бы не сказал что это сложно.

Comment: @Richard перечитайте что я написал...

Comment: @pavel Гм, я не настолько силен в теории чисел, чтоб так сразу уловить ваше предложение :( Но в любом случае получение остатка от вводимого 35000-значного числа - не самая простая задача?

Comment: @Harry один линейный проход. Второй класс умеет же в столбик делить) тут же длинное на короткое делить надо. Вот длинное на длинное уже тяжело.

Comment: @pavel Ну, может быть... Но все равно не пойму - ведь у произведения основная масса остатков будет 0 (ясно, если мы берем большие числа)? Что это даст?

Comment: @pavel Кстати, лучшее решение - всего 3 с чем-то миллисекунды - неужто таким способом?

Comment: @Harry почему? Берём _простое_ число порядка 10^9 - 10^15 диапазон, олимпиадники их наизусть знают, 1000003, 1000000007 100000037, 999999999989 ,1000000000039 ну и ряд других. Теперь считаем сложность. Строка 40к символов, вычисление модуля - линейно, 4 операции простейших на вычисление 1 модуля, тут их ну пусть 10 будет. Итого 1кк (округлим). Дальше можно уже что угодно творить, включая магию шаблонов =)

Comment: @pavel А сколько нужно таких чисел для гарантированного решения?

Comment: @Harry для гарантированного - чтобы их HOK был больше чем максимальное входное число. Но на практике более чем уверен что хватит 3. Они пойдут как хеш функции, они хоть и не сильно надёжны, но на фиксированных тестах более чем работают. Дайте ссылку на задачу попробую сдать.

Comment: @pavel Если хотите - то задача вот: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/28 Но меня интересует скорее подход - так сказать, всегда интересно узнать что-то новенькое. По крайней мере идея с остатками мне в голову, увы, прийти не могла (не настолько хорошо знаком с теорией, а уж про практику вообще молчу), поэтому я и заинтересовался.

Comment: @Harry с 1 раза в лоб - `25,49 ms / 72,55 ms` http://ideone.com/3N0pcY

Comment: @pavel Круто :) Надо пойти подчитать Кнута на эту тему... :)

Answer (score 3):

В общем раз всё равно написал код в комментарии, оформлю ответом.

```
char z[40000];

long long mod(long long mm){
    long long r = 0;
    for (int i=0; z[i]; i++){
        r %= mm;
        r*=10;
        r+= z[i] - '0';
    }
    return r%=mm;
}

int main ()
{
    gets(z);
    long long R[2];
    R[0] = mod(1000000000039LL);
    R[1] = mod(999999999989LL);
    for (int i=2;i<=10000;i++){
        long long Q[2] = {1,1};
        for (int j=i;j<=10000;j++){
            Q[1] *= j;
            Q[1] %= 999999999989LL;
            Q[0] *= j;
            Q[0] %= 1000000000039LL;
            if (Q[0] == R[0] && Q[1] == R[1]){
                printf("%d %d",i,j);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Просто вычисляем произведение по модулю. В нормальных задачах советую использовать ~10 простых числе для вычисления модулей.

P.S. тесты настолько слабые что можно обойтись вычислением по 1 модулю вместо многих.

Comment: @Richard проверьте что и куда вы отправили. У меня всё прошло.

Comment: @Richard ссылку дайте.

Comment: @Richard сюда пишите. Тут лички нету.

Comment: @Richard там не ограничение по времени, пишет что неверный ответ, но это явно глюки системы проверки. Разберитесь откуда читать надо и куда выводить.