# Найти номер заданного числа в последовательности Фибоначчи

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада, числа-фибоначчи

Сама задача: http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/fibonacci-sequence--ru, 
мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<long double> fib{0, 1};
    for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) // По условию все числа из первой тысячи
                                  // значений последовательности
    {
        fib.push_back(fib[i] + fib[i-1]);
    }

    int N; // Первая строчка должна содержать количество проводимых тестов
    cin >> N;

 long double value[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cin >> value[i];
}

    int begin, end;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(value[i] > fib[fib.size() / 2]) // Если value находится во второй половине последовательности
        {
            begin = fib.size() / 2;
            while(value[i] > fib[begin]) 
            {
                begin /= 2;
            }
            begin *= 2; // Возвращаюсь на шаг назад
                        // ибо после выполнения цикла
                        // value выходит из диапозона
            end = fib.size();
            for( ; begin < end; begin++)
            {
                if(fib[begin] == value[i]) {cout << begin << " "; break;}
            }
        }

        else
        {
            end = fib.size() / 2;
            while (value[i] < fib[end])
            {
                end /= 2;
            }
            end *= 2; // То же самое что и в первой ветви
            begin = 0;
            for ( ; begin < end; begin++)
            {
                if(fib[begin] == value[i]) {cout << begin << " "; break;}
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Можно было бы не делать такую дичь и просто написать

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < fib.size(); j++)
        if(value[i] == fib[j]) cout << j + 1 << " ";
```

Но во время чтения одной умной книжки мне стало интересно воссоздать упрощенную версию алгоритма binary_search() и в общем вот :)

На сайте с задачей также любезно предлагают ввод данных чтобы проверить прогу, мне дали такой:[image]

Ради небольшого теста я попробовал ввести только несколько из них, а конкретнее - самый первый, второй и четвертый.
К моему удивлению, все что я получил на выходе - это ничего.

Разочаровавшись в своем коде я переделал код до

```
vector<long double> fib{0, 1}; 
    long double value;
         cin >> value;

    int i = 1;
    int number_of_element = 1;
    while (value > fib.back()) {
        fib.push_back(fib[i] + fib[i-1]);
        i++;
        number_of_element++;
    }
    cout << fixed << "Element: " << fib[i-1] << " It's number: " << --number_of_element;
```

чтобы узнать, в чем я не прав и заодно проверить, мб просто числа попадаются больше первой тысячи. Вводил то же самое по очереди: первое, второе и третье числа из Test data.
Во всех трех результатах полученное прогой число было практически идентично введенному, приблизительно до 19 знака (я много раз сбивался со счета по этому это не точно), номер элемента тоже не превышал тысячи. Исходя из этого я сделал вывод, что у машины просто произошла ошибка после определенного количества знаков. Можно ли как-то исправить эту проблему?

Comment: нет. Дробное число long double хранит примерно 20 точных знаков (ну 21-22). Больше вы никак не получите. Но можете использовать длинную арифметику. Однако правильное решение - использовать вычисление по модулю (сравните с http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614950/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0/614970#614970)

Comment: @pavel, К сожалению, с теорией чисел я не силен, не могли бы вы описать чуть подробнее, что значит вычисление по модулю в данном случае? Т.е мне нужно записывать в вектор fib не само число, а взятое по какому-то модулю? И принимать, соответственно, тоже число взятое по этому же модулю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем ссылка на похожую задачу [Для каждого теста вывести в отдельной строке минимальный угол между стрелками в градусах в формате, приведенном в примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614950/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0/614970#614970) (я оттуда даже половину кода взял).

Код написан на коленке, его можно (да и нужно) сделать более аккуратным, но идею думаю понять можно.

А идея очень простая - мы просто делаем операцию по модулю простого числа (можно и больше чем одного, можно и не простого). И считаем что если совпало по модулю, то совпадёт и без модуля.

Почему это корректно, да можете просто проверить что в массиве чисел фибоначи в пределах первой тысячи нет одинаковых элементов.

```
char z[40000];

long long mod(long long mm){
    long long r = 0;
    for (int i=0; z[i]; i++){
        r %= mm;
        r*=10;
        r+= z[i] - '0';
    }
    return r%=mm;
}

int main ()
{
    vector< long long > xx;
    xx.push_back(0);
    xx.push_back(1);
    for (int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
        xx.push_back(
              (xx[xx.size() -1] +  xx[xx.size() -2]) % 1000000000039LL
        );
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin >> z;
        long long R = mod(1000000000039LL);
        for (int I = 0; I <= 1000; I++)
            if (R == xx[I]){
                cout << I<<" ";
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Можно сделать ещё проще, но тогда будет проблема, если на входе будет не число фибоначи. Это воспользоваться формулой Бине и тупо прологорифмировать основную часть. Точность низкая, но в 2 раза ошибиться тяжело. Ну и первые чисел 10 проверить руками. Плюс этого метода - что можно даже всю строку не читать, важно знать только первые 2 цифры (а может и 1 даже) и число цифр.

---

А вообще этот сайт подходит только для совсем начинающих, даже самые сложные задачи решаются без особых проблем.

Comment: А кстати, представим, что введено число неверно - ну, там, ошиблись на единицу в 115-м знаке... Что тогда выдаст ваша программа? Это не наезд, просто пытаюсь сообразить, в состоянии ли она выяснить, что введенное не является числом Фибоначчи?

Comment: @Harry одиночную ошибку точно проверит. Для увеличения точность нужно использовать ещё дополнительное 2 число (как в той задаче). Вероятность случайного неправильного распознавания порядка 0.1% в таком варианте и 10^-11 со 2 числом. Конечно подобрать пример всегда можно, но в случае с 5-6 числами это уже очень нетривиальная задача.

Comment: Я имею в виду, тогда остатки будут не совпадающие с правильными, так что число окажется не найденным, или, что хуже - найденным неверно?

Comment: @Harry ну это и имел ввиду, число окажется не найденным) формально - это же не число Фибоначи. а проценты писал о том что не число распознается как число.

Comment: Эти проценты сработают на ограничении <N. Если его не ставить - интересно, для любого ли остатка найдется соответствующее число? :)

Comment: @Harry а в этом смысле вопрос хороший. И очень таки математический. Думаю ответ будет зависеть от модуля. Для конкретного числа проверить можно, цикл будет не длинее чем модуль в квадрате, но в общем виде - не знаю).

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю более простой метод :) Поскольку единиц целых две, имеем проблему неоднозначности. Так что я работаю для чисел, начиная со второго, полагая единицу - вторым числом Фибоначчи...

Вот код, который дает номер числа, но не проверяет, верно ли введено число... Так что он даст ответ и НЕ для числа Фибоначчи. Будем надеяться, что на вход таковые не подаются - от нас не требовали распознавать, верное ли это число, правда?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s;
    while(getline(cin,s,'\n'))
    {
        int ex = s.length()-1;
        s.insert(1,".");
        double x = stod(s);
        int n = (log10(5.0)/2.0+log10(x)+ex)/log10((1.0+sqrt(5.0))/2)+0.5;
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Проверено для чисел от второго и до 1001-го (209-значного) :), ответы правильные...

Обоснование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Откуда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если считать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше вычисляем по формуле :)

Comment: а ещё можно пренебречь первыми 2 слагаемыми в числителе и сделать весь знаменатель константным. После чего формула будет вполне читаемая.

Comment: @pavel Можно. Но тогда будет не так очевидно, какой формулой мы воспользовались. В данном случае мне казалось, что понятность должна превалировать над скоростью.

Comment: а оно и сейчас не очевидно, в формуле Бине 2 слагаемых а не 1)

Comment: @pavel Даже для первых (ну, вторых :)) чисел вторым слагаемым можно пренебречь...

Comment: Немного трудно понять ваш код. Я так понимаю, что мы представляем входящее число string-ом, с помощью s.insert(1, ".") мы вставляем в s[1]  символ "." и за тем помещаем результат в double x. Дальше идет не понятная мне формула и вывод ее значения.
P.S. Есть вообще вопросы, на которые вы не ответили?))

Comment: @niki4iko прочитайте что такое формула Бине https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#.D0.A4.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.91.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B5 потом в целом всё понятно уже становится. А в целом - да примерно так.

Comment: А как же, есть :) Просто я работаю за компом, написал программку, которая отслеживает появление новых вопросов на SO, и открывает браузер, давая мне возможность отвлечься от неинтересной работы... Что до вашего вопроса - вот [тут](http://cyclowiki.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8) есть формула, в которой, отбросив первый член, я получаю легко разрешимую относительно n формулу - путем логарифмирования. Так как число может легко выскочить за предел представимости double, я представляю его в виде x.xxxxxx... (вставкой точки),

Comment: а степень вычисляю как длину строки (и просто прибавляю ее к десятичному логарифму). Все. Потом округляю полученный результат к ближайшему целому.